# How to connect to remote Oracle DB from airflow using oracle client in docker image

Tags: oracle, airflow

We have a use case,

if you have steps to connect to oracle from Airflow using oracle client can you please share ?

We have a python script with cx_Oracle dependant package. Now we are thinking of build our own docker image with instant client packaged

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some info on Docker with Instant Client is on https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python  It has a couple of links (search for "Update") with some useful Dockerfiles and images.  PS Don't get surprised if your question gets voted to be closed; it is too general for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones Jones for your reply. It was really helpful. How can we use this with our apache airflow as a base image apache/airflow:2.1.1-python3.8(which has debian os)